# how to replace placeholder from a source file.properties to another file.properties with Maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I'm learning how to replace placeholder of a file properties to another file properties with Maven. My project has a main folder named testMaven and I have created two files properties in the project, where the first file is situated in testMaven->local->value.properties and into the file there are:

user=testUser
password=testPassword

instead the second file properties situated into src/main/java->test.properties there are:

user=@user@
password=@password@

I would like to have into the file Jar a file properties with the fields replaced with:
user=testUser
password=testpassword

How do I write in the file pom.xml to do the description above?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, but I believe you are talking about filters. See an example: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to work with two plugins:

- [org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) to read the properties file with the values to be used
- [com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/) to make the substitution

The documentation available for both of them is straightforward.

### Update

Given a custom.properties file:

> custom.user=testUser
>   custom.password=testPassword

Read it with:

> ```
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
>             <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>${properties-maven-version}</version>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <phase>initialize</phase>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                     <configuration>
>                       <files><file>${jbake.inputDirectory}/custom.properties</file>
>                       </files> 
>                     </configuration>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>         </plugin>
> ```

Now, you need to run the replacer for each property:

> ```
>             <plugin>
>                 <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
>                 <version>${replacer-maven-version</version>
>                 <executions>
>                     <execution>
>                         <id>replace-for-documentation</id>
>                         <phase>prepare-package</phase>
>                         <goals>
>                             <goal>replace</goal>
>                         </goals>
>                         <configuration>
>                             <preserveDir>true</preserveDir>
>                             <basedir>${basedir}/src/main/resources</basedir>
>                             <outputBasedir>${basedir}</outputBasedir>
>                             <outputDir>src/site</outputDir>
>                             <ignoreErrors>true</ignoreErrors>
>                             <regex>false</regex>
>                             <delimiters>
>                                 <delimiter>@</delimiter>
>                             </delimiters>
>                             <filesToInclude>
>                                 *.properties
>                             </filesToInclude>
>                             <replacements>
>                                 <replacement>
>                                     <token>user</token>
>                                     <value>${custom.user</value>
>                                 </replacement>
>                                 <replacement>
>                                     <token>password</token>
>                                     <value>${custom.password}</value>
>                                 </replacement>
>                             </replacements>
>                         </configuration>
>                     </execution>
>                 </executions>
>             </plugin>
> ```

Any occurrence of @user@ or @password@ inside properties files under src/main/resources will be replaced. The generated files will be under src/site

Comment: But I don't undestand how to replace placeholder from another file.

Comment: Ok thanks for the response. But I would like automatic replace the placeholder and so I have used: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html